# Is this Haskell code efficient?

Tags: list, data-structures, haskell, performance

As a beginner exercise, I've implemented the following function to find the n-th element in a list:

```
elem_at (h:_) 0 = h  
elem_at (_:t) n = elem_at t (n-1)  
elem_at _ _     = error "Index out of bounds"
```

However, if I call: elem_at [1,2,3,4] 5, is it correct that it will return "Index out of bounds" only after having traversed the whole list, so that the last line matches the pattern _ _ with [] 1? More generally, if the list were *big* wouldn't that be a performance issue? Can ghc somehow optimize that situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, this is precisely the canonical way to index a list, almost. You need to add in checking for negative numbers

```
elem_at xs n | n < 0 =  error "elem_at: negative index"
```

And you could add a specific match for the empty list:

```
elem_at [] _         =  error "elem_at: index too large"
```

And the base and inductive case:

```
elem_at (x:_)  0         =  x
elem_at (_:xs) n         =  elem_at xs (n-1)
```

and you've got the Prelude definition of list indexing, the `(!!)` operator.

A slightly more efficient version can be yielded via the worker wrapper, floating the index test to the top level.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. But wait... to math [] _, starting with [1,2,3,4] and 5, I have to use the inductive case 4 times, right?

Comment: If n is too large, you'll hit the base case of elem_at [] _. This is good because if you compare the n to the length, you end up traversing the list once to get the length and then again to find the element.

Comment: @Tim you are right. Supplementary question: does Haskell store the length of a list internally so that querying it could be real fast?

Comment: Nope. You could write your own list that did, but then you couldn't use the built-in functions that operate on lists. There has been some talk of making the list type into a typeclass so it could be generalized, but I don't think anything has been done on that. Besides, @Don Stewart would be better at continuing that line of thought so I leave off here.

Comment: @Frank: no, lists are the simple recursive type, `data [a] = [] | a : [a]`. That's it. If your algorithm depends on indexing or length-taking, consider using finger trees or vectors (`Data.Sequence` or `Data.Vector`).

Comment: @Tim Perry: John Goerzon wrote the ListLike package, which is a set of type classes which provide list functions.  Currently there are instances for lists, arrays, bytestrings, Sequences, vectors, and text (the last two are in a separate package).  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike

Comment: Thanks @John L. That may save me some coding one day *very* soon. (as in tomorrow)

Comment: @Frank: if it did then you would have trouble with infinite lists... :$

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the haskell implementation is about as efficient as traversing a singly-linked list in any language. If the data were stored in a different structure, then the you could answer the question without traversing the list.

Comment: My "issue" is that I like the code above very much, because it's so concise. It would be ideal if I could write nothing more, and still have very efficient code at runtime. I have written another version that triggers the error on out of bounds faster (I think), but it's not as elegant.

Comment: If you have a static list and you just want quick look-ups, you might get an efficiency improvement by converting your list to an array. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Modern_array_libraries